# Is this a bad structure for a proto file

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, proto

Have run into huge difficulties while trying to make a gRPC app with mulitple services and have been unable to find the cause of my issues. Starting to think it may be in the structure of the proto code.

```
message Room {
    enum Location {
        Unknown = 0;
        Hallway = 1;
        MaleWC = 2;
        FemaleWC = 3;
        Office = 4;
        Kitchen = 5;
        ConferenceRoom = 6;
    }
    Location room = 1;
    int32 capacity = 2;
    int32 population = 3;
    bool light = 4;
    bool lock = 5;
}
 
service lightandtempcontrol {
 
    // create a name for the rpc first -> then specify type of message to send to server
    // to turn a light on upon somebody entering a room
    rpc LightsOn(targetLight) returns (emptyMessage) {}; // Unary*
    // to turn a light off upon someone entering the room
    rpc LightsOff(targetLight) returns (lightReceipt) {};
    //to regulate temperature dependent on the temperature outside
    rpc OutsideTemp(stream outTemp) returns (stream indoorTemp){}; // Bidirectional*
    //to get a complete 
    rpc Usage(usageRequest) returns (stream lightUsage) {}; // Server streaming example
 
}
```

Basically, I am trying to create a Room class that I can use with multiple services, getting and setting fields across those services but everytime I try to base code off of one of these I am getting undesired results, mostly because the values I want to change or compare are not working at all. Is the issue in the structure of my proto. is it possible to use this Room message inside other services outside of lightandtempcontrol?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @AlphaModder , apologies for the formatting

Comment: What "undesired results" are you seeing? What is "not working at all" about comparing/changing values? What are the definitions of `targetlight` and the other RPC messages?